# Schedular call to OSB proxy in regular interval

Tags: osb

I am very new in OSB. I have created one proxy service which call separate business services. I want to configure it such a way that the proxy service get automatically called after every 5 minutes. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

(Is the result of the proxy call to be dismissed?)

Besides a correct way (implementing a in-process or out-of-process scheduler), there is also a hack (well, not totally hack; just "not intended use"):

You may have a JMS queue primed with a single message. The queue should be configured to have a very large retry number with the given interval (300s). Another proxy, JMS one, with transactions=ON should read the queue and call your original proxy, and then raise a fault to rollback the transaction.

Note that rolling back a message produces a long stack trace in OSB logs, so you may consider to filter some log IDs in Weblogic.

Comment: That will result in a slight skew, since it will be 300s+(however long it takes to process and roll back). That may be fine for most scenarios though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I Know, for this you will need to call OSB from BPEL. OSB doesn't provides this functionality out of the box. Or you may want to create a scheduler as explained here: https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/weblogic_scheduling_a_polling

Comment: Adding BPEL into the system just for scheduling sounds like an overkill, don't you think? ;)

Comment: @VladimirDyuzhev Agree!!